# Order of a Subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let, $A \subset S_n$, $S_n$ is a symmetric group.

$|A| \leq \log (n!)$.

$A$ generates a subgroup $G$ of $S_n$. i.e. $\langle A \rangle=G < S_n$.

What is the order of $G$? Can it be bounded by $|A|$ ?

Answer (score 2):

Since $S_n$ can be generated by two elements, there is no hope for a better bound for the order of $\langle A \rangle$ than $n!$ when $\log(n!) \ge 2$, that is, when $n\ge 4$.

In other words, this bound is sharp:

> If $|A|\ge 2$, then $\langle A \rangle \le n!$.

The trivial case is trivial:

> If $|A|=0$, then $\langle A \rangle = 1$.

The interesting case is $|A|=1$, which needs [Landau's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%27s_function) $g(n)$:

> If $|A|=1$, then $\langle A \rangle \le g(n) <e^{n/e}$.

This bound is sharp by definition.

Bounds for $g(n)$ are $ g(n) <e^{n/e}$ and $g(n) \le \exp\left(1.05314\sqrt{n\log n}\right)$.

Therefore, the answer to your last question is that the order of $\langle A \rangle$ can be bounded by $|A|$ (or a function of $|A|$) only in the trivial case when $A$ is empty.